# Add padding to images to get them into the same shape

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

l have a set of images of different sizes `(45,50,3), (69,34,3), (34,98,3)`. l want to add padding to these images as follows:

Take the max width and length of the whole images then put the image in that size

```
import os
import glob
import cv2

input_path="/home/images"
os.chdir(indput_path)
images=glob.glob("*.png")
Length=[]
Width=[]
for img in images:
    img=cv2.imread(img)
    width,length=img.shape[0:2]
    Length.append(length)
    Width.append(width)
W=max(Width)
L=max(Length)
```

How can l add padding in opencv so that all the images will have the same size? In the example l gave the images will get the shape of `(69,98,3)`

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044061/add-padding-to-object-in-4-channel-image

Comment: @Zindarod. l have black and white images pixels are either 0 or 255 only. most of my characters in images are written in black. So l need white pixel padding. However l have also some images where the characters are in white so l need black pixel padding. l'm wandering if there is a trick in open cv to detect that then add white or black pixel padding

Answer (score 76):

You can use:

```
image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(src, top, bottom, left, right, borderType)
```

Where `src` is your source image and `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` are the padding around the image.

You can use max(sizes) - size value of the image in a while loop to add the padding to each image.
The bordertype can be one of these:

- `cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT`
- `cv2.BORDER_REFLECT`
- `cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101`
- `cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT`
- `cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE`
- `cv2.BORDER_WRAP`

[`cv2.copyMakeBorder` tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html#:%7E:text=making%20borders%20for%20images%20(padding))

Comment: how can l get top bottom left and right values. l have just width and length that l can get from image.shape

Comment: @vincent _"You can use max(sizes) - size value of the image"_

Comment: you can add values only to left or top, or add half of the width and length values to all directions. like: top = length/2, bottom = length/2, left = width/2, right = width/2

Comment: @Azadef, please see my update. it didn't perfom correclty on dimension

Comment: This definitely needs to show the code for actually getting the dims for both images, and then resizing both (because one might be wider while the other is taller) using this approach.

Answer (score 41):

Here is another way to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy. It uses Numpy slicing to copy the input image into a new image of the desired output size and a given offset. Here I compute the offset to do center padding. I think this is easier to do using width, height, xoffset, yoffset, rather than how much to pad on each side.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
old_image_height, old_image_width, channels = img.shape

# create new image of desired size and color (blue) for padding
new_image_width = 300
new_image_height = 300
color = (255,0,0)
result = np.full((new_image_height,new_image_width, channels), color, dtype=np.uint8)

# compute center offset
x_center = (new_image_width - old_image_width) // 2
y_center = (new_image_height - old_image_height) // 2

# copy img image into center of result image
result[y_center:y_center+old_image_height, 
       x_center:x_center+old_image_width] = img

# view result
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("lena_centered.jpg", result)
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer but naming variables as 2 letters is unreadable and bad practice.

Comment: `@Paul Feakins` So what would you suggest in place of what I have?

Comment: "height", "width" etc. are usually fine.

Comment: In Python examples, one often sees,`h,w,c = img.shape` So single letters are OK, but not double letters? No one wants to type height and width all the time.! Nevertheless, I do understand the concern for readability and understanding

Comment: "No one wants to type height and width all the time.!" Haha! You think that's bad you should see some of the code I've seen recently, stuff like "discountPriceBeforeTaxIsApplied" etc. So there is a balance to be had, and I know yours is quite a simple script, but I personally think being a bit more descriptive with the variable names would aid readability.

Comment: I would generally agree with you. I was just being lazy and most people know what w, h mean. But I prefer to reserve those for the results of the bounding box. Perhaps wd and ht might have been better choices, if not the full width and and height names. Thanks for the comment. I will try to be better about this in the future.

Answer (score 18):

try to use this function:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps


def padding(img, expected_size):
    desired_size = expected_size
    delta_width = desired_size[0] - img.size[0]
    delta_height = desired_size[1] - img.size[1]
    pad_width = delta_width // 2
    pad_height = delta_height // 2
    padding = (pad_width, pad_height, delta_width - pad_width, delta_height - pad_height)
    return ImageOps.expand(img, padding)


def resize_with_padding(img, expected_size):
    img.thumbnail((expected_size[0], expected_size[1]))
    # print(img.size)
    delta_width = expected_size[0] - img.size[0]
    delta_height = expected_size[1] - img.size[1]
    pad_width = delta_width // 2
    pad_height = delta_height // 2
    padding = (pad_width, pad_height, delta_width - pad_width, delta_height - pad_height)
    return ImageOps.expand(img, padding)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = Image.open("./demo.jpg")
    print(img)
    img = resize_with_padding(img, (500, 400))
    print(img.size)
    img.show()
    img.save("resized_img.jpg")
```

Raw image

[image]

After resizing with padding

[image]

see https://gist.github.com/BIGBALLON/cb6ab73f6aaaa068ab6756611bb324b2

Answer (score 14):

Like this (Padding is called borders on openCV):

```
BLUE = [255,255,255]
constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(image.copy(),10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLUE)
```

And blue can become white even

source: 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 9):

As I do not see an accepted answer, and also the fact that one has to determine the top, bottom, left, right of the function, I have bellow what worked for me easily. Taken from: https://jdhao.github.io/2017/11/06/resize-image-to-square-with-padding/

```
import cv2

desired_size = 368
im_pth = "/home/jdhao/test.jpg"

im = cv2.imread(im_pth)
old_size = im.shape[:2] # old_size is in (height, width) format

ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])

# new_size should be in (width, height) format

im = cv2.resize(im, (new_size[1], new_size[0]))

delta_w = desired_size - new_size[1]
delta_h = desired_size - new_size[0]
top, bottom = delta_h//2, delta_h-(delta_h//2)
left, right = delta_w//2, delta_w-(delta_w//2)

color = [0, 0, 0]
new_im = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
    value=color)

cv2.imshow("image", new_im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What if I want the height/width of the resulting image to differ? For example, only pad height but leave width as is.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Without testing it, I would guess that in the `im = cv2.resize(im, (new_size[1], new_size[0]))` you will have to change one of the new_size with old_size. The first one is for keeping height constant and the second of width

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function doing all for you :

```py
import cv2


def pad_images_to_same_size(images):
    """
    :param images: sequence of images
    :return: list of images padded so that all images have same width and height (max width and height are used)
    """
    width_max = 0
    height_max = 0
    for img in images:
        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        width_max = max(width_max, w)
        height_max = max(height_max, h)

    images_padded = []
    for img in images:
        h, w = img.shape[:2]
        diff_vert = height_max - h
        pad_top = diff_vert//2
        pad_bottom = diff_vert - pad_top
        diff_hori = width_max - w
        pad_left = diff_hori//2
        pad_right = diff_hori - pad_left
        img_padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, pad_top, pad_bottom, pad_left, pad_right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)
        assert img_padded.shape[:2] == (height_max, width_max)
        images_padded.append(img_padded)

    return images_padded
```

Comment: Works on both grayscale and RGB. Thank you!

Comment: I call the function like this: pad_images_to_same_size(["image1.jpg,image2.jpg]). The error appers <AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'> what is wrong in this case?

Comment: @N.white you need to pass images already loaded as numpy ndarrays, and not image paths

Answer (score 5):

Here a single line could do it

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
image = Image.open("demo.jpg").convert("RGB")
ImageOps.pad(image,(100,100)).save('imaged-with-border.png')
```

This will keep my image in `100x100` maintaining its aspect ratio with `zero` padding

Comment: This answer lacks explanation. `ImageOps.pad` not just pads to the size of choice, but also performs upscale/downscale first. The paddings and fill color are configurable.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @sebl ful. It should work with either black and white image or color image

```
def resize_with_padding(image, shape_out, DO_PADDING=True, TINY_FLOAT=1e-5):
    """
    Resizes an image to the specified size,
    adding padding to preserve the aspect ratio.
    """
    if image.ndim == 3 and len(shape_out) == 2:
        shape_out = [*shape_out, 3]
    hw_out, hw_image = [np.array(x[:2]) for x in (shape_out, image.shape)]
    resize_ratio = np.min(hw_out / hw_image)
    hw_wk = (hw_image * resize_ratio + TINY_FLOAT).astype(int)

    # Resize the image
    resized_image = cv2.resize(
        image, tuple(hw_wk[::-1]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST
    )
    if not DO_PADDING or np.all(hw_out == hw_wk):
        return resized_image

    # Create a black image with the target size
    padded_image = np.zeros(shape_out, dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # Calculate the number of rows/columns to add as padding
    dh, dw = (hw_out - hw_wk) // 2
    # Add the resized image to the padded image, with padding on the left and right sides
    padded_image[dh : hw_wk[0] + dh, dw : hw_wk[1] + dw] = resized_image

    return padded_image
```

Comment: what do you mean by shape_out and what is an image type in the header of your function? Is it array or what? your code didn't run with me. Please, defind the parameters that passed to the resize_with_padding.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Pillow's `crop_pad()`. It automatically resize and adds 'zeros' padding where needed (rgb=(0,0,0) / black) with no picture scaling.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(your_file_path)
img.crop_pad((width, height))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the best what i could do, works only with black and white images

```
def resize_with_padding(image, size=(224,224)):
    '''
    Resizes a black and white image to the specified size, 
    adding padding to preserve the aspect ratio.
    '''
    # Get the height and width of the image
    height, width = image.shape
    
    # Calculate the aspect ratio of the image
    aspect_ratio = height / width
    
    # Calculate the new height and width after resizing to (224,224)
    new_height, new_width = size
    if aspect_ratio > 1:
        new_width = int(new_height / aspect_ratio)
    else:
        new_height = int(new_width * aspect_ratio)
        
    # Resize the image
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (new_width, new_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    
    # Create a black image with the target size
    padded_image = np.zeros((224,224), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # Calculate the number of rows/columns to add as padding
    padding_rows = (224 - new_height) // 2
    padding_cols = (224 - new_width) // 2
    
    # Add the resized image to the padded image, with padding on the left and right sides
    padded_image[padding_rows:padding_rows+new_height, padding_cols:padding_cols+new_width] = resized_image
    
    return padded_image
```

Answer (score 0):

As [George](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50504336/17121398) said above he wrote the best solution I have found, here I converted it into a function that resizes images while respecting the aspect ratio, it best works with squares, I don't need to change the square aspect as I'm training for deep-learning model.

```
def resize_me_with_ration(im , desired_size = 200):
    old_size = im.shape[:2] # old_size is in (height, width) format
    ratio = float(desired_size)/max(old_size)
    new_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in old_size])
    # new_size should be in (width, height) format
    im = cv2.resize(im, (new_size[1], new_size[0]))
    delta_w = desired_size - new_size[1]
    delta_h = desired_size - new_size[0]
    top, bottom = delta_h//2, delta_h-(delta_h//2)
    left, right = delta_w//2, delta_w-(delta_w//2)
    color = [0, 0, 0]
    new_im = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=color)
    return new_im
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function using Pillow and Opencv which takes an image in numpy.ndarray format and outputs an image also in numpy.ndarray format with your desired height and width without changing aspect ratio and just apply padding. It does not matter which height and width your image has in the first place.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

def resize_image(image, height, width):
    image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
    MAX_SIZE = (width, height)
    image.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE)
    image = np.asarray(image)
    y_border = max(height - image.shape[0], 0)
    x_border = max(width - image.shape[1], 0)
    top = y_border // 2
    bottom = y_border - top
    left = x_border // 2
    right = x_border - left
    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return image
```

you can use the function as follows:

```
image = resize_image(image, 320, 320)
print(image.shape)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Besides, if you want the function takes image_path as input instead of image in numpy format you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

def resize_image(image_path, height, width):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    MAX_SIZE = (width, height)
    image.thumbnail(MAX_SIZE)
    image = np.asarray(image)
    y_border = max(height - image.shape[0], 0)
    x_border = max(width - image.shape[1], 0)
    top = y_border // 2
    bottom = y_border - top
    left = x_border // 2
    right = x_border - left
    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return image
```