# How can I solve the problem of pytorch program?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to run python program using pytorch with my own dataset.I come across with the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 345, in 
    fire.Fire(demo)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 138, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 468, in _Fire
    target=component.**name**)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 672, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 323, in demo
    n_epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 202, in train
    n_epochs=n_epochs,
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 83, in train_epoch
    output = model(input)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 555, in **call**
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\models\densenet.py", line 151, in forward
    features = self.features(x)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 555, in **call**
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 100, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 555, in **call**
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 100, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 555, in **call**
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\pooling.py", line 557, in forward
    self.padding, self.ceil_mode, self.count_include_pad, self.divisor_override)
RuntimeError: Given input size: (150x1x1). Calculated output size: (150x0x0). Output size is too small
Please guide me how to sove this problem.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the input size of the image. It has to be exactly the same as specified in the model. You can use padding if the image is smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much!The input size is:torch.Size([1, 3, 3, 158])

Comment: Can't say anything without knowing your model. Keep in mind that, When you pass the input down the model, the sizes get smaller and smaller especially with max pooling. So if you input a small image, the output gets very low dimension in the middle, making it impossible to go down the rest of the model.

Comment: Thanks!Please answer how to use padding.

Comment: That's a seperate question. Search before asking. Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391205/add-padding-to-images-to-get-them-into-the-same-shape

Comment: Thanks you very much!