# python: Show numpy padded image by opencv

Tags: python, opencv

In opencv in python I loaded an black and white image. After resize this image I added pading 5 pixel into each side of image :

```
resized_digit = cv2.resize(digit, (18,18))
cv2.imshow("resized Image", digit)

# Padding the digit with 5 pixels of black color (zeros) in each side to finally produce the image of (28, 28)
padded_digit = np.pad(resized_digit, ((5,5),(5,5)), "constant", constant_values=0)
```

How can I‌ show padded_digit by opencv? Because when I try to show like this:

```
cv2.imshow("Padded Image", padded_digit)
```

I got this error:

```
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-295bf6efa8c4>", line 39, in <module>
    padded_digit = np.pad(resized_digit, ((5,5),(5,5)), "constant", constant_values=0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in pad

  File "/home/Alt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py", line 746, in pad
    pad_width = _as_pairs(pad_width, array.ndim, as_index=True)

  File "/home/Alt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py", line 521, in _as_pairs
    return np.broadcast_to(x, (ndim, 2)).tolist()

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in broadcast_to

  File "/home/Alt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 180, in broadcast_to
    return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)

  File "/home/Alt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 123, in _broadcast_to
    it = np.nditer(

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2) and requested shape (3,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the problem by reading with `cv2.imread` and then convert to the gray-scale (black-and-white) image to the `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized_digit = cv2.resize(gry, (18, 18))
padded_digit = np.pad(resized_digit, ((5, 5), (5, 5)), "constant", constant_values=0)
cv2.imshow("padded_digit", padded_digit)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`imread` loads the image in BGR fashion, then you can convert it to the gray-scale using `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`.

You can also use `copyMakeBorder` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391205/add-padding-to-images-to-get-them-into-the-same-shape)) instead of `np.pad`. Using `np.pad` is not wrong, but `opencv` is more suitable for image operations, since you are using `opencv` functions like `imshow`, `waitKey` etc.

For instance:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized_digit = cv2.resize(gry, (18, 18))
padded_digit = cv2.copyMakeBorder(resized_digit, 5, 5, 5, 5, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)
cv2.imshow("padded_digit", padded_digit)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can check the two image equality by comparing their shapes. Both of them `print(padded_digit.shape)` will be `(28, 28)`

Comment: Thanks. This is original image and resize and padding image https://pasteboard.co/JNw246F.png . The resized and padded image why has bad quality ? mean why has Edged all the side? How can i improve so that all edges be soft like main image?@Ahx

Comment: You need to use [interplotaion](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) parameter while resizing you image. For instance: `resized_digit = cv2.resize(gry, (18, 18), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)`

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JNwc04b.png , This is end of improvement? Because I want to add into my model that created from mnist dataset to predict image number to number @Ahx

Comment: Wait! resizing mnist? why are you resizing mnist digits?, they are already `28, 28`? yet you can easily reach 99.2% accuracy, without any preprocessing.

Comment: No, I resized my handwriting image to be same mnist image @Ahx

Comment: Well if you are going to do learning, then try the current state of the images. Try, the outputs of the `resized_digit = cv2.resize(gry, (18, 18), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)` .

Comment: Keep in mind that the current state-of-the-art of mnist is [99.79%](https://benchmarks.ai/mnist)

Comment: Yes but when you want to predict real image number in some numbers like 6 , It can't predict good. So I added some augmentation to fix the problem .Now my model's accuracy is 99.4 and It can predict 100 percent from my handwriting image number. I use CNN to create model@Ahx

Comment: Thats perfect, congrats