# Add transparent padding to image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How can I add transparent padding to all images in a specific directory?

So for example I have images with a resolution of 100x100px and want to add:
20px top,
10px right,
40px bottom,
20px left.

Comment: See this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391205/add-padding-to-images-to-get-them-into-the-same-shape Let me Know if it helps ..

Comment: Convert to `RGBA`, and use [`ImageOps.expand`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.expand). The `border` parameter can be a 4-tuple, and for the `fill` color, use anything `(R, G, B, 0)`.

Comment: you can always get image size, create new empty image with bigger size, and finally `paste()` old image on new image in the center. But version @HansHirse can be better. Eventually you could try to use directly `ImageMagic` without `Python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
for imagePath in os.listdir(inPath):

    # imagePath contains name of the image
    inputPath = os.path.join(inPath, imagePath)

    # inputPath contains the full directory name
    img = Image.open(inputPath)

    # fullOutPath contains the path of the output
    fullOutPath = os.path.join(outPath, imagePath)

    # add padding
    img = ImageOps.expand(img, border=(10,10,10,10), fill=(0,0,0,0) )

    # image that needs to be generated
    img.save(fullOutPath)

    print(fullOutPath)
```

Comment: A prerequisite that might not be too obvious to beginners is that you need to make sure that you 'img' is set to RGBA mode i.e. supports showing the Alpha channel along with the RGB channels. A PIL image could be converted as follows: `img = img.convert("RGBA")`